# Adding padding in C3JS Stackbar chart

Tags: c3.js

How to add space in a stack chart using C3JS as shown below 
[image: Stack Bar Chart]

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of simulate it using this css rule, but not exactly -->

```
.c3-bar {
    stroke-width: 3;  /* pick a number */
    stroke: white !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/px439vmv/261/

However, I'd argue it's a bad idea to have big gaps between items in a stack, because either
1) You need to take the space for the gap from the stack item itself (which is what the above css does), which makes it seem smaller, and for very short items in the stack can remove them completely from view.
or
2) You need to add extra space in between the stack items, which will make the total for a stack appear to be more than the sum of its parts i.e. two stacks which are '3' tall will look more than '6'. The more items in a stack, the worse this gets.

Comment: Though I understood the point you raised but I think the 2nd option is more prudent and that will make more sense as the whole of chart will be standardised with more height. But for small values if the figure won't appear then it will create lot of havoc. Could you please provide a sample code to achieve the 2nd option